# Leaderboard doesn't close because I can't declare the GKGameCenterDelegete

Tags: xcode, swift

I can't put `GKGameCenterControllerDelegate` 
In my class. And `GameKit` is already imported
And my button to get to the leader board works and it has the function to close it but it when I press done it doesn't close.

I try to write it like this

Code:

```
class GameScene: SKScene, GKGameCenterControllerDelegate {
```

This is the button I get an Error on "`gc.gameCenterDelegate = self`"

```
let location2 = touch.locationInNode(self)
        if self.nodeAtPoint(location) == self.TrophyButton {


            var vc = self.view?.window?.rootViewController
            var gc = GKGameCenterViewController()
            gc.gameCenterDelegate = self
            vc?.presentViewController(gc, animated: true, completion: nil)

            funcgameCenterViewControllerDidFinish(gameCenterViewController: GKGameCenterViewController!)
            {
                gameCenterViewController.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)


            }
```

Comment: Have added GameKit under BuildPhases link with BinaryLibary?

Comment: No I don't think so where is that at?

Comment: Ok that's not the problem idk think the main problem is that "gc.gameCenterDelegate = self".      It gives my an error that says "Cannot assign a value of type 'GameScene' to a value of type GKGameCenterControllerDelegate"

Answer (score 0):

[image]Try Add Gamekit als BinarayLibary, simply Click left on your projet, then you will see some tabs as general, info ... click on the Build PhasesTab go to the Link Binary With Libraries extend it and click Plus search for GameKit.

Comment: Ok that's not the problem idk think the main problem is that "gc.gameCenterDelegate = self". It gives my an error that says "Cannot assign a value of type 'GameScene' to a value of type GKGameCenterControllerDelegate" –